# Qual seria o equivalente ao find para listas no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

O que seria equivalente ao find usado em strings para usar em listas? Por exemplo, se é `a=['a','b','c']`, como retorno a posição 1 do `'b'`?

Comment: O que quer fazer? Saber se existe o valor na lista ou buscar em qual índice o valor se encontra?

Comment: se esta até sei mas quero saber em qual indice esta. Com o mesmo objetivo do find que é usado para string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método `find`, de *string*, retorna o menor índice onde é encontrado o valor buscado. Em listas, existe o método [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> numeros.index(3)
2
```

Isto é, fazendo `numeros.index(3)` retornará o índice onde está o número 3 - lembrando que o índice inicia em 0, portanto o terceiro valor estará no índice 2.

Se o valor não for encontrado, uma exceção `ValueError` será lançada.

```
>>> numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> numeros.index(9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 9 is not in list
```

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, e desculpe pela pergunta elementar.

Comment: @BrenoFaria Não precisa se desculpar. Qualquer dúvida é válida.